# How to update Datatables with fresh parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am using datatables with serverside processing. I am trying to filter the table based on the some params but I cannot get the new params to be sent to the server. Datatables always uses the old params

**This is what I have**

```
oTable = $('#mainDataTable').DataTable( {
        paging:         true,
        searching:      false,
        scrollY:        docHeight,
        //scrollX:      300,
        stateSave:      false,
        info:           true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "http://myurl/"+getParameters(); //start=1&end=50&foo=bar",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false, // do not cache
                    url: sSource,
                    data: aoData,
                    success: function (json) {
                        fnCallback(json);
                    }
                });
        },
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
```

**I tried** to update the parameters by calling draw(false) but it sends the old parameters to the server. I also tried `table.ajax.url( url ).load()` again it sends the old parameters.

I went through datatables.net and found some examples like below

```
oTable = $('#mainDataTable').DataTable( {
        paging:         true,
        searching:      false,
        scrollY:        docHeight,
        //scrollX:      300,
        stateSave:      false,
        info:           true,
        "bServerSide" : true,
        "sAjaxSource" : "http://myurl/"+getParameters(),
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false, // do not cache
                    url: sSource,
                    data: {
                        "start": $("#start").val();
                        "end":  $("input[name=end]").val(); 
                        "foo":  $("input[name=bar]").val();
                    },
                    success: function (json) {
                        fnCallback(json);
                    }
                });
        },
```

This **seems to work but** now my server is not being passed `iDisplayStart`, `iDisplayLength` etc which I rely on for pagination

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a function instead of variable it should be like:

```
 function getPostData(tableParams) {
        return  $.param(tableParams) + "&" + $.param({
                ID:$('#Id').val()
            });
    }
```

then:

```
ajax: {
            url:proxyPath + modulePath +'getList',
            data: getPostData
        },
```

You can use this, enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this example may help you...

In jQuery, everytime the select input changes value, it fetches JSON data using POST, the parameter defined here is the value of the select, also you can pass other parameters using the POST command (in my example is "key"):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var table = $('#mainDataTable').DataTable();
    table.clear().draw();
    $.post('scripts/fetch-some-data.php', {
        key: $('select').val()
    }, function(data) {
        table.rows.add(data).draw();
    }, 'json');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on right track ... In Server Side code catch new params like.

```
       public ActionResult 
       Get([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] 
       IDataTablesRequest requestModel, string start, string end, string foo)
       {//all Code here  }
```